# How to Access Index of Array in the properties of AGE Vertex When passed to PG_Catalog Function

Tags: database, postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I have created a `vertex` student:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
CREATE (s:student{name:"Muneeb", courses: ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", "Android"]})
 RETURN s
$$) as (student agtype);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     student    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

{"id": 3377699720527873, "label": "student", "properties": {"name": "Muneeb", "courses": ["OOP", "DS", "Programming", "Android"]}}::vertex
    (1 row)
```

It contains courses in its property, which has list of courses in it.

I have created a function that should return 2nd index of the List, in `PG_Catalog`.

```
test=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.second_in_list(list agtype)
RETURNS agtype AS $$
BEGIN
   return list[1];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

When I call this function:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
Match (s:student) Return pg_catalog.second_in_list(s.courses)
$$) as (student agtype);
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot subscript type agtype because it is not an array
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT list[1]"
PL/pgSQL function second_in_list(agtype) line 3 at RETURN
```

I have tried passing list `agtype[]` as argument to `pg_catalog` function but it also not work.

Comment: Based on the docs, only void or scalar value functions are supported https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/advanced/sql_in_cypher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that through accessing the **agtype** list using the **->** operator

```
test=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.second_in_list(list agtype)
RETURNS agtype AS $$
BEGIN
   return list->1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

**While keeping rest of your code as it**

In AGE, -> is the operator used to access elements of an AGE array by index or keys of an AGE JSON object.

The **reason** your function doesn't work is that it tries to use the subscript operator [] to access the first element (index 1) of an agtype object, which is not an array. That operation is invalid and leads to the error you saw.

**In contrast**, using the -> operator, which is used to navigate the graph and retrieve values from a vertex or an edge property in Apache AGE. In this case, when you call **list->1**, it returns the value associated with the key 1 from the agtype object. The -> operator is the correct operator to use when you want to retrieve a value from a dictionary-like structure like an **agtype**.

So, in **summary**, -> is the right operator to retrieve a value from a dictionary-like structure, as long as that **agtype** is **non-array** structure, which is invalid to use **[]** at SQL query.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the custom function you have created you can't access list item as its type is agtype and to access the second element of the array you need to run a cypher query instead of plain sql query. So either don't create a custom function and directly access the element as given below:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$
Match (s:student) Return s.courses[1]
$$) as (student agtype);
```

or add the query itself in the

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.second_in_list()
RETURNS TABLE(course agtype)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$ Return s.courses[1] $$) as (student agtype);
END
$BODY$;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then use

```
Select * From second_in_list();
```

to get the desired result